# @Cacheable on non spring managed class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache

I need to use ehcache on non spring managed class, like an utility class. It's not working. I tried to initialize utility class object but still no luck. The Reason I'm going for object creation is, this particular class cannot be singleton object because this class has Some other class variables, which values are different from other object of same class. So I cannot annotate this class with `@Component`

**Utility Class**

```
public class DirectoryReader implements IReader {

    // Some other class variables, which values are different from other object of same class Ex. Delete the file after read.
    private boolean deleteFilesAfterRead;
    @Cacheable(cacheNames="directoryContent", unless="#result.length() > 0")
    public String getContent() {
        //Read a file and get data;
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Object Creation**

```
@Component
public class ReaderUtility {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Bean(name="readers")
    public List<IReader> determineReader() {
        DirectoryReader directoryReader1 = new DirectoryReader();
        DirectoryReader directoryReader2 = new DirectoryReader();
        applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(directoryReader1, "directoryReader1");
        applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(directoryReader2, "directoryReader2");
        // List<IReader> readers = .....
        // return readers;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The Reason I'm going for object creation is, this particular class cannot be singleton object becase this class has Some other class methods and variable which is different from other object of same class."* This doesn't make any sense. If they have different methods and fields, they're not the same class.

Comment: @SeverityOne I'll update question, what I meant was different value for the filed.

Comment: Spring need to proxy the objects where you want to leverage it's functionality. You may want to reconsider the structure of your code to move the @Cachable to a managed bean

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar Got it, but not sure if spring supports multiple bean for same class. If so I can use that. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If making a singleton is the issue, why not use `@Scope("prototype")` so that a new bean is created with each request? This is what you should do for beans that are stateful as is your case.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

> **4.4.2 The prototype scope**
>
> The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the
>   creation of a new bean instance every time a
>   request for that specific bean is made (that is, it is injected into
>   another bean or it is requested via a programmatic getBean() method
>   call on the container). As a rule of thumb, you should use the
>   prototype scope for all beans that are stateful, while the singleton
>   scope should be used for stateless beans.

You can then update your utility class to this:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class DirectoryReader implements IReader {

    // Some other class variables, which values are different from other object of same class Ex. Delete the file after read.
    private boolean deleteFilesAfterRead;
    @Cacheable(cacheNames="directoryContent", unless="#result.length() > 0")
    public String getContent() {
        //Read a file and get data;
        return "";
    }
}
```